# How does type promotion work in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Consider the following code snippet -

```
def factorial(number) {
    if(number == 1)
        return number;
    else 
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
}

println factorial(50)
println factorial(50).getClass()

println()

println 45**20
println ((45**20).getClass())
```

The output is -

```
0
class java.lang.Integer

1159445329576199417209625244140625
class java.math.BigInteger
```

Questions -

1. Why doesn't groovy automatically promote the result of `number * factorial(number-1)` to a `BigInt` in the first case?
2. Why is the output 0? Why isn't it some random number that we should get after integer overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but I'll try to answer both parts of the question:

[Groovy documentation on arithmetic operations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math) states that

> > binary operations involving subclasses of `java.lang.Number` automatically convert their arguments according to the following matrix (except for division, which is discussed below)

I won't paste the matrix but it specifies no casting to `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` unless one of the operators is of one of these types.

In the case of division:

> > The division operators "/" and "/=" produce a Double result if either operand is either Float or Double and a BigDecimal result otherwise

I think that the table is not considering the power operator (`**`) since it's not present in Java and as stated in @tim_yates comment, `power` implementation uses `BigInteger` by default.

The [code in `DefaultGroovyMethods.java`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L10934) shows clearly that the power of `int`'s is calculated using `BigInteger`'s and if the result is small then is cast down to int again (And that's why `(2**4).class` is `java.lang.Integer`):

```
public static Number power(Integer self, Integer exponent) {
    if (exponent >= 0) {
        BigInteger answer = BigInteger.valueOf(self).pow(exponent);
        if (answer.compareTo(BI_INT_MIN) >= 0 && answer.compareTo(BI_INT_MAX) <= 0) {
            return answer.intValue();
        } else {
            return answer;
        }
    } else {
        return power(self, (double) exponent);
    }
}
```

To confirm the behaviour of other operations you can go to [`IntegerMath`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/IntegerMath.java), [`LongMath`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/LongMath.java) or other classes in the [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling package](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/tree/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling)

Comment: My apologies I didn't see this answer until today. +1 for pointing to the actual source.

Answer (score 0):

With Groovy, `Integer.multiply( Integer )` always returns an Integer.

The factorial method starts overflowing around step 16.

At step 34, you end up with `-2147483648 * -2147483648` which returns 0 so the result will always be 0

One fix is to change your method declaration to:

```
def factorial( BigInteger number ) {
```

Comment: Another fix would be `factorial(50G)`. But I'm confused how there is an automatic promotion to BigInt in case of `**`. `10**4` is Integer, `10**45` is BigInt. Is there an automatic type promotion is case of overflow? Why can't same be done for `*`?

Comment: [Calling power goes through BigInteger](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L10382) -- The groovydocs state _"Power of an integer to an integer certain exponent.  If the exponent is positive, convert to a BigInteger and call BigInteger.pow(int) method to maintain precision. Called by the '**' operator."_

Comment: So result of exponentiation should always be BigInt. Right? Then why does `print ((2**4).getClass())` print `java.lang.Integer`.